# How can I update this sed oneliner?

Tags: sed

INPUT:

```
 $ echo -e 'AAAART5530408XXXX\nAAAAZE6530408XXXX\nAAAART12345678XXXX'
AAAART5530408XXXX
AAAAZE6530408XXXX
AAAART12345678XXXX
$
```

OUTPUT:

```
 $ echo -e 'AAAART5530408XXXX\nAAAAZE6530408XXXX\nAAAART12345678XXXX' | sed -e 's/\(AAAA[A-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{7\}\)XXXX/\n\1/g'

AAAART5530408

AAAAZE6530408
AAAART12345678XXXX
$
```

How can I extend the:

```
sed -e 's/\(AAAA[A-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{7\}\)XXXX/\n\1/g'
```

sed oneliner, so that it would optionally accept

```
sed -e 's/\(AAAA[A-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{8\}\)XXXX/\n\1/g'
```

8 numbers too? (not just 7) Is it possible with only 1 sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\{7\}` construct is a simple case of the `\{m,n\}` for "match at least `m` and at most `n`, in your case it'll be:

```
sed -e 's/\(AAAA[A-Z]\{2\}[0-9]\{7,8\}\)XXXX/\n\1/g'
```

Perhaps a simple:

```
sed -s 's/XXXX//g'
```

is enough in your case?